# How to store just the 'access_token' value in a cookie from the returned Curl response? (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, cookies, access-token, setcookie

Im trying to store the access token returned from the google OAuth2.0 , to let the users make api calls. The returned value from the curl request is a String. ( `gettype($response)` ) 
Now the whole string is being stored as a cookie.

This is the response:

```
{ "access_token": "ya29.Il-wB-gorL-****", "expires_in": 3600, "refresh_token": "**bQtt8C8zJro", "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos", "token_type": "Bearer" }
```

How can I get just the value of 'access_token' in this code line?:

```
setcookie("token", $response, time()+14400, "/");
```

i have tried to use `$response->access_token` but then it gives me errors because that cannot be applied to strings.

Comment: `$response = json_decode($response); echo $response->access_token`

Comment: @Nick i tried that but it still gives me the whole respone

Comment: It works for me: https://3v4l.org/G5GvJ